# How to set intellij compile error output language to English?

Tags: intellij-idea, javac

my windows 7 os is in Chinese, and location is China. My `javac` output is in Chinese as well. However, I can add `-J-Duser.language=en` to `javac` to output english. I would like to know how to set this up in intellij?
I have tried to put `-J-Duser.language=en` in

```
File->Setting->Build,Execution,Deployment`->Java Compliler->Additional Command line parameters
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Try `-Duser.language=en` option instead.

Answer (score 7):

I had tried and confirmed that the `Java Compiler / Additional command line parameters` options didn't work

And so modified the `idea.vmoptions` (add one line) worked:

```
-Duser.language=en
```

Which's file located here for macOS

```
$HOME/Library/Preferences/$IDEA
```

on now `$IDEA` should be `IntelliJIdea2017.2`

Comment: You can open vm options by: Menu - Help - Edit Custom VM Options

Answer (score 0):

After some googling, I found a way of doing it.
I can delete these two files from  `\lib\tools.jar`

```
com\sun\tools\javac\resources\compiler_zh_CN.class
com\sun\tools\javac\resources\javac_zh_CN.class
```

However, I wonder if there is a less destructive way.

Answer (score 0):

From the menu "help"->"Edit Custom VM Options", open the VM options,
add a line : -Duser.language=en
save, then restart the intellij